# Zend Studio with Remote Host option doesn't work in VPN networks & Android USB tethering mode

Tags: android, ftp, zend-studio, filezilla, tethering

I'm using Zend Studio with Remote Host option (FTP) for working & testing directly in hosting. However, when I connect internet with my university's network, Zend Studio doesn't upload the code to the host. But, when I use FileZilla, it works correctly. The situation is same when I use 3G connection USB tethering mode in Android.

Note : I've checked my firewall settings. The settings seem to be correct.

Any ideas to make Zend Studio upload the code ?

By the way, I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that passive mode is not chosen in managing the ftp connection / account. If you choose passive mode, then everything works fine